# rqt won't start

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tried multiple ways of starting up rqt and each time the, it starts to load and seems to get stuck and so I'm left with a blank box and can't proceed any further.[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288124/rqt-won%27t-start/) by [The_Developer_02](https://answers.ros.org/users/34565/the_developer_02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
Can you please add a screenshot of what you see? RQT without any plugins is a "blank window", so that might be perfectly ok.

(note: this is about the only time adding a screenshot makes sense, hence my question)

**Comment by [The_Developer_02](https://answers.ros.org/users/34565/the_developer_02/) on 2018-04-10**:
does that help?

**Comment by [liuyoudehama](https://answers.ros.org/users/38945/liuyoudehama/) on 2018-12-10**:
same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but if this is a recent Ubuntu version, then it could be that this is just a basic RQT window with no plugins loaded. If you could verify that the menu appears when you hover over the title bar, then you could try loading a plugin.

If this is the case, it's an Ubuntu UI thing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [The_Developer_02](https://answers.ros.org/users/34565/the_developer_02/) on 2018-04-10**:
Yes, thank you, sorry I'm reasonably new to Ubuntu and I forget the menu is along the top. Thank you

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
Ok, good to hear that nothing is 'broken' then.